# Bash output (triming string)

Tags: bash

Can someone explain to me, what exactly am i trimming? Like everything, that the \n, the head, the cut, the -d etc. means.

```
classnumber=$(cat "ClassTimetable.aspx?CourseId=156784&TermCode=1620" | tr '\n' '\r' | head -n 1 | cut -d '>' -f1235- | cut -d '<' -f1)
```

Thanks

Comment: So you want us to explain your code?

Comment: Yes, im tired of guessing which numbers to use because i dont understand the concept. thanks

Comment: learn to use `man` pages for each program, i.e. `man cut`. Good man pages include an 'examples' section near the bottom. Also learn to test 1 cmd at a time, ie. `echo a,b,c | cut -t, -f2` Then add a 2nd piped program, etc, etc experimenting. Good luck.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/

Comment: This is looking very much like a massively unmaintainable attempt to scrape a single value out of a piece of HTML.  Don't use regex or line-oriented tools for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat "ClassTimetable.aspx?CourseId=156784&TermCode=1620" | \
    tr '\n' '\r' |       # replace Line Feed with Carriage Return
    head -n 1 |          # take what's in the first line
    cut -d '>' -f1235- | # take everything after the 1235th '>' until end of line
    cut -d '<' -f1)      # take the first chunk before the first '<'
```

Experiment with it to understand what it does, for example try to reduce it to

```
echo "1>2>3>4>5>6>7>8>9>10>11>12>13><14>15" | cut -d '>' -f12- | cut -d '<' -f1
```

And come up with an explanation on how does that work.

Comment: Great experiment you provided to me, i kind of understand but why is -f12- the '>' between 12 and 13 yet the output is 12>13>? unless 0 is a valid counting number?

Comment: going more specific to my problem i have, how do i define to take like line 235?

Comment: If you need to get a specific line you might want to use `awk 'NR==2'` for ex if you want line 2, rather than `head -n 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trimming

1. \n , \r
2. First line
3. Getting field, 1,2,3,5 (until end of line). '>' is the delimiter
4. And from result of 3, getting the first column ('<' is the delimiter)

Comment: OP is not trimming `\n` and `\r`, but replacing. `cut -d '>' -f1235-` does not start with fields 1,2,3,5 but it starts with field 1235.